# How can i use config variables in jsx file without importing in jsx?

Tags: reactjs

i have created 1 configuration file in **public/environment.js** and return object from config file.

i also include this config file in **public/index.html**

**how can i use this object in all .jsx file without import?**

I do following

> public/environment.js

```
glbVar = {
  HOST_ENV: "REACT_APP_HOST_ENV",
  SOCKET_ENV: "REACT_APP_SOCKET_ENV"
};
```

i have include **environment.js** file in **index.html** and i am able to use this ***glbVar***

> public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

  <script src="./environment.js"></script>

  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

<script>
  console.log("glbVar index file", glbVar);
</script>

</html>
```

But i am not able to direct use this **glbVar** in **.jax** file.

***How can i use this glbVar in all .jsx file without import environment.js file***

Thanks in advance...

Comment: if you're using create-react-app `dotenv` comes baked in... https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to export that global variable like that:

```
export const glbVar = {
  HOST_ENV: "REACT_APP_HOST_ENV",
  SOCKET_ENV: "REACT_APP_SOCKET_ENV"
};
```

Then in your **.jsx file** you will need to import it:

```
import { glbVar } from "./path-to-your-environment.js-file" // note that this is the relative path to your environment file`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

but i want to use **glbVar** in all **.jsx** file.

so can i use without import **environment.js** file in **.jsx**??

Comment: You can assign your variable to the window object like that: window.glbVar = glbVar. That way you can use it everywhere without importing it.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Mark the question as answered and happy coding!